# Concierge Pass Through Software

Tags: cloud-service

I run a company where we manage the common areas and facilities for residents in a community.  Our company is setting up what we call a "Concierge" service.  My needs for this service, in a nutshell, would be to keep track of several vendor's prices.  They could be anything from Pest Control, Special Landscaping, Transportation Arrangements, even Airline/Travel Scheduling to House Cleaning, Air Filter changeout (inventory mgmt?), etc.

Here are the main tasks I would need to accomplish with the software:

- Receive a request from customer, schedule request with customer & vendor to arrange service.  Send confirmation to both customer and vendor (email) of service date & price.
- Place a reminder on a calendar (preferable integration with mobile).
- Receive invoice from vendor after service is complete, let's say it's $50.00
- Bill customer with the built in pricing from my company, let's say we add on 5% to the 50.00, so 52.50.  Or it could be a set $ fee. (this is added in on top of the vendor's price).  They do not see what the vendor charges me, just what I am passing through to them.

Anything like this out there?

Context: *Basically the idea is to easily setup this second part of my business as a trusted vendor program.  I negotiate good bulk prices for the customer with convenient scheduling through someone they already know and trust.  Ability to offer many services and the software does all of the tracking, scheduling, confirmations, billing, future service reminders... etc.*